# Next Greater Even Number

Tags: algorithm, stl-algorithm

We have a number N and the problem is to find the smallest even number E such that E > N and digits in N and E are same. Digits in N could be huge.

For example

1. 1 -> 34722641 answer would be 34724126
2. 111 -> no even number is possible just greater then it.
3. 1123 -> output would be 1132

I have done it with brute force by making all the permutations of the digits of the number. I was thinking if a better approach is there for it? A code would be better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following strategy in finding the next permutation:

Lets say your `number = 12344875`
To find the next permutations which is bigger, you start from the right and find the first number is smaller than the previous one.
In this case: number = 1234**4**875, this is 4.

Now you start from the 4 moving right and find the smallest number there. 
Which is the 5 -> 87**5**. Now swap those 2 numbers resulting in 1234**5**87**4**.

After the swap sort the numbers after the 5 in ascending order. 12345**874** --> 12345**784**. 
This strategy will always lead to next permutations wich is bigger, only this gives both even and uneven numbers.

So for finding the next even permutations, you need to change this slightly.
If in last step you have an even number, permutate that part till its an even number.

Otherwise start again from the right. And find the first even number, which has a larger number to its right side. For example with the number = 123**4**75531.
Now swap with smallest number to its right which is greater than **4**.
Resulting in the following 123**5**75**4**31.

From this put the even number **4** at the end and put the numbers between 
the swapped numbers in ascending order, 1235**7531**4 --> 1235**1357**4.

For the case were you have the following number 136531. There is no even number with a greater number to the right. So you look at the next number,
and see if to the right there is a number wich is greater (but not the first even number). Here it is for 1**3**6531 --> 136**5**31 so swap those and put the even number at the back and finally put in ascending order. 136531 --> 1**5**6**3**31 --> 15331**6** --> 15133**6**.

There is no solution when the number is in descending order(for example 97654).

While making this explaination I realised that for an even number this gets more convoluted. Ill try to improve the answer later on.

I hope this was useful.
Cheers

Comment: You approach seems fine. But I was thinking if it could be more optimized sort of order O(nlogn). or rather if we could avoid that permutation which you mentioned if the number comes out to be odd.

Comment: I won’t have time today. I try to make a pseudo code tonight, for the uneven/even case.

Comment: And I think to be honest that the above is alwayes in the order of O(n). You dont actually have to permutate anywhere, that was just a quicker description. You can at that phase just pick the largest even number and put that last and put the rest of the numbers in ascending order. 1235131863 -->  123513**1**863 --> 123513**3**86**1** -->  1235133**18**6.

Comment: But you are doing a sort that itself makes it (nlogn) as the number can have digit of huge order. Still finding a better solution anyways thanks for the effort .

Comment: Your example of **976173** has **977136** as the next greater even number. Update your answer. **You missed a very important case where there's an even digit and there's another equal even digit on its right side.** For eg - 123646531 and 123696531.

Comment: Ah i see, like i said in the answer. I had no time to work out the problem completely. 

As the answer is already accepted, i am not going expand the answer. But feel free to edit or give your own.

Comment: 3rd last para last line. this->`But also in cases where there is 1 even number which has no higher number to his right. And the numbers to left of the even number have no number greater to the right of them (for example 976173).`

Answer (score 0):

Find the rightmost digit, `i`, that has a higher digit, `j`, to its right, where `j` is not the highest even digit to its right, `e`. Pick the smallest such `j`, switch `i` and `j`, place `e` as the rightmost digit, and sort (ascending) the digits to the right of where `i` was (excluding `e`).

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the **next greater number** for a given number. For eg - for 1234, the next greater number is 1243 and for 534976 the next greater is 536479.
   The algorithm can be found [here.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-next-greater-number-set-digits/) If the last digit is even then you've found the next greater even number.
2. Otherwise, repeat the above step until we find the even number.ie-find the next greater even
   number than this with the now the new input number as the one that
   we output in the previous step (even if we didn't find the desired
   output(greater even number))

For eg - Input number - **21856521**, running the first steps yields - **21861255**(odd) so we again run step 1 on **21861255** which yields **21861525**(again odd), running again yields **21861552**

PS: C++ code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s;cin>>s;
    int n = s.length();
    while(true){
        int idx = -1;
        for(int i=n-2;i>=0;--i){
            if(s[i]<s[i+1]){
                idx = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(idx==-1){
            cout<<-1<<endl;
            break;
        }
        int swapidx = -1;
        for(int i=n-1;i>=idx+1;--i){
            if(s[i]>s[idx]){
                swapidx = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        swap(s[idx],s[swapidx]);

        //swapidx will never remain -1 bcz. we will surely find an element greater than s[idx](the right next element to idx is greater than s[idx])


        sort(s.begin()+idx+1,s.end());

        if((s[n-1]-'0')%2==0){
            cout<<s<<endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @GijsDenHollander `If the last digit is even then you've found the next greater even number. Otherwise, .....repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getNextEven(self,x):
    s,p,flag,r = [],0,0,int(x)
    for i in x:
        p +=int(i)
        if int(i)%2==0:
            flag=1
        s.append(i)
    
    if flag==0:
        return -1
     
    n,x = len(s),int(x)
    
    while r%2!=0 or r<=x:
        l,k = -1,-1
        for i in range(n-2,-1,-1):
            if s[i]<s[i+1]:
                k = i
                break
        if k==-1:
            return -1
        
        for i in range(k+1,n):
            if s[k]<s[i]:
                l = i
               
        
        s[k],s[l] = s[l],s[k]
        s = s[:k+1]+s[k+1:][::-1]
        r = int(''.join(s))
        
    return r
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).